# Default fixtures not uploaded to production

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

I am using django nonrel and I've created a default fixture for my app as `initial_data.json`.

When I do a syncdb locally, this fixture is indeed loaded into the DB.

However, when I deploy the app using `manage.py deploy` the fixture doesn't seem to make it into the production DB, even though syncdb says it does.

```
....
01:36 PM Uploading index definitions.
01:36 PM Uploading cron entries.
Running syncdb.
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 1274 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
$
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is it being installed in a different database?

Comment: This is the only database for this app. I would assume it is not installed in another app

Comment: Is this running on Google App Engine?